# Enum's values() method access level

Tags: java, reflection, enums

JLS 8 [states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3) that each enum class has implicitly declared method:

```
public static E[] values();
```

So, it is `public` by specification.

At the same time `Class.getEnumConstantsShared()` method forcibly makes it accessible:

```
            final Method values = getMethod("values");
            java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
                new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
                    public Void run() {
                            values.setAccessible(true);
                            return null;
                        }
                    });
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T[] temporaryConstants = (T[])values.invoke(null);
```

I'm wondering: what's the sense?

Comment: Probably related to this comment: "These can happen when users concoct enum-like classes that don't comply with the enum spec." http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Class.java#2961

Comment: Ha, nice. And how is that possible to "concot" such class? O_o

Comment: Before enums were introduced in Java 5, it was a common practice (and a good practice) to make your own equivalent of an enum:  A class with a non-public constructor, and public static constants containing instances of that class.  Examples are [TextAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html), [FileChannel.MapMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.MapMode.html), and [DateFormat.Field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.Field.html).

Comment: @VGR that's interesting point,but those classes **doesn't contain** `values()` methods.

Comment: I'm guessing you can concoct such a class by extending Enum instead of using the `enum` keyword. Worst case, you can always generate an enum-looking class using direct bytecode generation.

Comment: @kaqqao classes can not directly extend `java.lang.Enum`. It is prohibited by compiler. Furthermore, `Class.getEnumConstantsShared`  has protection against non-enum classes via invoking method `Class.isEnum`.

Comment: Both of those can easily be bypassed by a bytecode generator... Look at ByteBuddy for example. You can generate a class of any structure, including those Java compiler would never normally let you.

Comment: It is perverted case, I don't believe that discussed code was created to handle such cases. Furthermore, using this approach of bytecode generator, I can easily generate enum class w/o `values()` method. Where is protection from this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: otherwise it would not work with anything but public `Enums`

To access the method `MyEnum.values()`, the method needs to be public (it always is) and `MyEnum` needs to be `public` (or it must be in the same package).

The method is accessed from the `Class::getEnumConstantsShared()` in the package `java.lang`. So as long as the none public Enum is not in `java.lang` `getEnumConstantsShared()` will not have access to it. Access is determined by the **direct caller** not by somebody higher up the call stack. The direct caller of `values.invoke(null)` is the code in `java.lang.Class` so the accessibility rules apply to exactly that context

That can be easily verified (following code will **not** work) if you create a static method in some package `a`

```
public class ValueGetter {
    public static Object[] getValues(Class<? extends Enum> enu) throws Exception {
        Method method = enu.getMethod("values");
        return (Object[]) method.invoke(null);
    }
}
```

And try to access it like this snippet in **a different** package `b`

```
public class EnumTest {
    enum MyEnum {
        LITERAL;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ValueGetter.getValues(MyEnum.class)));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a good point, I even firstly accepted your answer. But then I begin thinking: access to this method is performed only inside same context where this enum is accessible. Furthermore, it is accessed inside class itself.

Comment: In other words, you can invoke `valueOf(...)` on particular enum only when this enum is accessible and visible.

Comment: It is actually the same as write `Object values = MyEnum.class.getMethod("values").invoke(null);` - it will work without forcibly making `method.setAccessible(true)`.

Comment: `ValueGetter` needs to be in a different package for this to actually cause an exception. The `Class` object is mainly independent from the class source, especially (for most cases) it is not in the same package. Enum.valueOf( Class, String ) uses `getEnumContantsShared()`. To call MyEnum.valueOf(String) normal visibilty rules apply.

Comment: Yep, I understand that `ValueGetter` needs to be in different package. And I totally agree that it doesn't work without settings method accessible to true. But the problem is that you practically can not invoke `getMethod("value")` on `MyEnum` class from different package: you always will do it from same package, or generally speaking: from scope of enum accessibility.

Comment: Just try understand my concern: invocation of `MyEnum.getEnumConstantsShared()`  and `ValueGetter.getValues(MyEnum.class)` is totally different things (from scope point of view).

Comment: P.S. As I'm currently little bit tired, I suppose that I can be wrong, that is why I'm not downvoting your answer, waiting for insights and opinion of other users.

Comment: In other words: there is no practical case, when you can invoke `valueOf` on particular enum, while `values()` method will not be accessible.

Comment: For accessibilty only the **direct caller** is relevant not the caller of the caller. The direct caller of `values.invoke(null)` is the code in `java.lang.Class` so the accessibility rules apply to exactly that context. That the method is called through `MyEnum.class.getEnumConstantsShared()` and the method was visible at that context is not longer relevant for accessiblity.

Comment: Fine, at least you convinced me :)

Comment: @FlorentBayle please award your bounty to this perfect answer!

Comment: @Andremoniy Done :-).